# SQL query count if datediff after grouping

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a single table, first 3 entries are like so:

```
 name   | jobnum | startdate | enddate

 name1  | 1      | 15/2/1990 |  11/3/1990
 name2  | 2      | 12/2/1991 |  13/2/1991
 name1  | 3      | 15/1/1997 |  11/2/1998
```

I need to group them so

it'll show

```
name | #jobs | # of times job ends before 30 days
```

I know how to show the first 2 columns. But the last one confuses me.

```
SELECT Table1.name, Count(Table1.start) AS #jobs
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.name
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below, it is untested, I believe you can just subtract dates in Access, though if not use the same theory but the datediff function....

```
SELECT Table1.name, Count(Table1.start) AS #jobs, 
    sum(IIF(Table1.enddate - Table1.Startdate < 30,1,0)) As LessThan30Days
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.name
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked. I'm assuming the 30, 1 , 0 accounts for the days/month/years difference?

Comment: Syntax for the formula is to sum the result of the IIF formula, the  30 is the number of days (the criteria), the 1 is what to return if it satisfies the criteria ( < 30 ) or 0 if it doesn't, thus for each time the difference in date is less than 30 it adds 1, if it is 30 or more days difference it adds 0.